# Generated queries contain schema and catalog name

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, informix, java-ee-5

I've the same problem as described [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=997341&start=0)

In the generated SQL Informix expects `catalog:schema.table` but what's actually generated is

```
catalog.schema.table
```

which leads to a syntax error.
Setting:

```
hibernate.default_catalog=
hibernate.default_schema=
```

had no effect. 
I even removed schema and catalog from the table annotation, this caused a different issues : the query looked like that `..table` same for setting catalog and schema to an empty string.

Versions

- seam 2.1.2
- Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA.CP01
- Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1.cp08
- Hibernate EntityManager 3.3.2.GAhibernate
- Jboss 4.3 (similar to 4.2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the one of the worst hacks I evever did:

The colon is the offending char wich should be '.' `catalog:schema.table`.

Informix allows comments in SQL statements `select {comment} * from sometable`

So I set

```
hibernate.default_catalog={
hibernate.default_schema=}schemaname
```

the resulting code looks like

```
select * from {.}schemaname.tablename
```

which is accepted by informix query parser.

Comment: Choose this answer as accepted otherwise this question will appear on unanswered

Comment: @Shervin I still hope for another answer perhaps someone else has a better solution, I haven't had the time to check Johnathans.

Comment: I had same problem and it solved by removing 'schema' and 'catalog' from @Table annotation in Entity

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a new (as of 2010-04-26) web page, http://www.iiug.org/opensource, that has information about using Informix software with various open source packages, including Hibernate. In particular, there is downloadable code that improves the interaction of Hibernate and Informix.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this provides patches for a distinct hibernate version, I will check that later.

Comment: Unfortunatly It's a different version of hibernate, besides that the  build fails 'Embedded error: uanble to execute po2xml : Cannot run program "po2xml": CreateProcess error=2'

Comment: po2xml is a known (even if not well-known) program - it may be that there's an undocumented dependency on that.  A search with Google shows that it is available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `schema` and `catalog` attributes from `*.hbm.xml`.